# Adwords Editor 11.6

Tags: wine, google, editor

I am having trouble installing the latest (must have) version 11.6 of Google Adwords editor. Worked fine till the previews version. But now we need to have the new version in order to work with it and because of the new rules. I tried installing it via wine and play on Linux, it won't even install because in the beginning of the installation I get a message saying that the installer could not connect to the internet, and asks me to check my firewall. There must be a solution to this problem, does anyone know know to fix this problem?

Comment: Please check the comments here: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=32146

Answer (score 0):

Set your Wine as "Windows 7" and install Google Adwords Editor with:

```
wine msiexec /i ./google_adwords_editor.msi
```

Source: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bShowAll=true&bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=version&sTitle=&sReturnTo=&iId=32146

Answer (score 0):

**ETA:** The download link for the MSI is now located at https://dl.google.com/dl/adwords_editor/google_adwords_editor.msi . If this link also stops working, you can contact Google Ads support directly and ask for them to send the most recent version file to you.

---

Similar to what CelticWarrior said: You need to install with the .msi file rather than the default setup .exe.

[The instructions here](http://adsppcmanagement.com/adwords-editor-on-ubuntu/) generally work. To get the .msi file you need to use a direct link to Google's download, using 4 digits in the version number. AdWords Editor 11.7 is at `dl.google.com/adwords_editor/`**`11.7.0.0`**`/google_adwords_editor.msi`, for example.