# AdWords editor installed ok but disappears when run

Tags: wine, google

**Goal:** Use Adwords editor in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS normally as I can with Windows.

**Background:**
I installed AdWords Editor 12.3.3.0 using the .msi with Wine set to Windows 7. Worked perfect.

The program installed successfully but when I click on it, it does not run. Nothing at all happens.

I have also tried changing the Windows version in the wine settings without luck so far.

Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Budgie Desktop on a Lenovo Thinkpad.

Similar to this question:
[Adwords Editor 11.6](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840008/adwords-editor-11-6/1047584)

**Question:** Does anyone know of a solution that will get AdWords to run?

Comment: Please, is your problem Wine or the Adwords editor? From what I can see, I think it is the editor and in that case, your question belongs to a different StackExchange site. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: You need to ask for help at https://forum.winehq.org/

Comment: We need more detail. How *exactly* did you "install[…] AdWords Editor […] with Wine"? Which steps did you take? Which applications did you use, which commands did you run?